# How to keep a pushButton of Qt be down after I click it?

Tags: qt, button

I would like to implement a group of pushButtons like painting tool chose in Adobe Ps:

- only one button can be checked at any time
- keep button be down after I click it

I have used `setAutoExclusive(true)` to meet the first requirement. So the next step is to deal with the second... Please give me some advice or suggestion?

Comment: [read documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractbutton.html#checkable-prop).

Comment: To be fair, the docs could explain a little what "checkable" means instead of explaining checkable with "checkable".

Answer (score 7):

```
QPushbutton button;
button->setCheckable(true);
```

or just click on the "Checkable" check box in designer

Answer (score 0):

Like suggested by another answer, you can create a QPushButton by e.g.

```
button = new QPushButton("Button text", this);
```

and then make it checkable with

```
button->setCheckable(true);
```

For this to have a visual effect, you need a section in your stylesheet (.qss) for
`QPushButton:checked`. If you have a section for `QPushButton:pressed`, you can just add it there, i.e. change

```
QPushButton:pressed {
```

to

```
QPushButton:pressed,
QPushButton:checked {
```

If you don't, the styling you need depend on the appearance of the button in its `pressed` state, which in turn depends on your operating system, so you have some guesswork to do.